# Finding best match based on smallest difference between rows

Tags: r

I have combined two datasets and it is not a 1 to 1 relationship. I must now identify the best match (between rows) based on a time delay.

I have tried this in MySQL and in R and haven't been able to find anything.

My initial data looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame("sent_id" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
     "recieved_id" = c(100,101,100,101,105,106,107,105,106,107), 
   "delay" = c('00:00:00','15:00:00','-00:14:59','00:00:01','23:00:05','00:01:00',
                   '-18:00:00','15:00:00','23:00:00','00:30:10'))
```

And I want to end up with something like this:

```
data2 <- data.frame("sent_id" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
     "recieved_id" = c(100,101,100,101,105,106,107,105,106,107), 
     "delay" = c('00:00:00','15:00:00','-00:14:59','00:00:01','23:00:05','00:01:00',
    '-18:00:00','15:00:00','23:00:00','00:30:10'), 
'best_match' = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Comment: Which time unit is delay? What is best match definition?

Comment: Do you mean the variable type? 'delay' is of type character currently. And the best match is the smallest amount of total time for each 'sent_id' (since 'sent_id' is not a unique value).

Answer (score 0):

Got rid of the negative signs in the delay and did the following.

`test_data <- data.frame("sent_id" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), "recieved_id" = c(100,101,100,101,105,106,107,105,106,107), "delay" = c('00:00:00','15:00:00','00:14:59','00:00:01','23:00:05','00:01:00','18:00:00','15:00:00','23:00:00','00:30:10'))`

`received_id <-unique(test_data$recieved_id)`
`sent_id_2 <-unique(test_data$sent_id)`

`library(dplyr)`

`new.frame <- data.frame("sent_id" = NA, 
                        "recieved_id" = NA, 
                        "delay" = NA)`

`for(i in 1:length(test_data$sent_id)){
  new.frame[i,] <- arrange(test_data %>% filter(sent_id == sent_id_2[i]), delay)[1,]
}`

Cleaned it up a bit for the actual code. But this will get you there.